# Non domain computer shares printer to domain computer. Frequent access denied

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer, domain

I have 2 computers. One is not part of a domain and other is. Both are running Windows 7

The printer is attatched to the non-domain computer and shared. The printer is installed in the domain computer.

Every few days the domain computer gets: `Access denied` when trying to print. The only solution I have found is to reinstall the printer, but it is getting pretty annoying.

Is there another (better) solution?

Comment: Join the non-domain computer to the domain... Very easy solution. The two computers don't trust each other and if the computers don't "shake hands" (I.e. credentials to access the shared printer are forgotten) then it's not surprising you get access denied. This is exactly the same when non-domain computers access each others shared folders (apart from "home groups"). Is there a reason why the computer isn't on the domain?

Comment: That assumes a windows version with domain support though (which is win-78 professional, enterprise and ultimate. No domain is supported on starter, basic and home versions).

Comment: It is not that. The computer that is not in domain controls laser cuting machine. So if I add computer to the domain I have to copy all user files to the server profile?

Comment: Is the printer share setup in Windows using the network address or IP address??

Comment: Using UNC \\computername\samsung printer. Usually printing works for 2 days and then it's access denied again. Modified printer security setting, no use. Only way I can install printer is browse \\computername and then right click install. Add printer wizard will not find printer

Answer (score 0):

You could share the printer on the network using a hardware Print Server - [like this](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=232&model=TL-PS110U#over).